# .htaccess redirect to lowercase ignored in subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a .htaccess that redirects everything to it's lower-case equivalent. For example:

example.com/HellO/WorLd -> example.com/hello/world

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Is it possible to overwrite this beheviour in the subfolder /admin? So that example.com/admin/WorLd would not change?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RewriteCond` to exclude the `/admin` folder from your RewriteRule.

Put the following condition right above your `RewriteRule` line :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
```